# Replacing values in an R dataframe with part of existing value name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe
    `nlmem3coef = data.frame(b0 = c(-1.453651,-1.423549,-1.497282,-1.398282,-1.453145,-1.387556,-1.415699,-1.430086), CompPlot = c("1/5/1","1/5/2","1/5/3","1/5/10","1/10/1", "1/10/2", "1/10/3", "1/10/10"))`

In the second column titled "CompPlot", I am only interested in the number in between the slashes and after the second slash. Therefore, I would like to make the values in the second column be:

```
`c("5.1", "5.2", "5.3", "5.10", "10.1", "10.2", "10.3", "10.10")`
```

So, is there a way to take my existing values in the CompPlot column and use only a portion of them and add the period in between the numbers. Secondly, considering that I have values over a single integer between the slashes and after the slash, could this code be flexible to get both 5.1 and 5.10 as well as 10.1 and 10.10 from my original data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gsub` and capture the relevant groups:

```
gsub("\\d+/(\\d+)/(\\d+)", "\\1.\\2", nlmem3coef$CompPlot);
[1] "5.1"   "5.2"   "5.3"   "5.10"  "10.1"  "10.2"  "10.3"  "10.10"
```

Or use `strsplit`:

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(nlmem3coef$CompPlot), "/"), function(x)
    paste(x[2], x[3], sep = "."));
[1] "5.1"   "5.2"   "5.3"   "5.10"  "10.1"  "10.2"  "10.3"  "10.10"
```

---

### Sample data

```
nlmem3coef = data.frame(
    b0 = c(-1.453651,-1.423549,-1.497282,-1.398282,-1.453145,-1.387556,-1.415699,-1.430086), 
    CompPlot = c("1/5/1","1/5/2","1/5/3","1/5/10","1/10/1", "1/10/2", "1/10/3", "1/10/10"));
```

Comment: @bxcrunner I've offered two earlier & alternative solutions that work on both your original and updated sample data; not sure how this *didn't* answer your question; also not sure why you removed comments.

Comment: I don't know why comments were deleted. I noticed some glitch in responding to the other poster, as he commented first with helpful information (but then he must have been editing his answer becuase it disappeared) and I tried to respond and it wouldn't let me. Your comments were also super helpful and spot on, which I stated and voted. This is my first post on Stackoverflow, so perhaps I've not done something right. And again, I don't know where my comments went because I had nothing but good things to say. I appreciate you help!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your code worked perfectly on my data!

Comment: @bxcrunner No problem. Your question is absolutely fine, so no issues there whatsoever. The disappearing comments are strange. But either way, glad it worked out and your question was answered.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sub()`.

```
sub(".*/(.+)/(.+)", "\\1.\\2", nlmem3coef$CompPlot)
# [1] "5.1"   "5.2"   "5.3"   "5.10"  "10.1"  "10.2"  "10.3"  "10.10"
```

Regular expression explained:

- `.*/` - remove everything before the first forward slash
- `(.+)` - store multiple occurrences of any character
- `/` - match a literal forward slash
- `(.+)` - store multiple occurrences of any character

The replacement `\\1.\\2` takes the first stored set `.+` and the second stored set `.+` and puts a `.` character between them.

Comment: Thanks Rich, that is successful!  I should also add that I have numbers in between the slashes that are also two integers (i.e. 10). The code you provided gets rid of the first of the two integers, so I end up with 0.1 when it should be 10.1. Any thoughts to tweak it slightly? I added an additional . (so ..+), which gets the first integer that was missing but grabs the first slash that I want to get rid of.

Comment: @bxcrunner - Please check my edit based on your updated question.

Comment: Your edit works great and answers my updated question. Thanks again!